# Add column in ObjectListView 2.5, SharpDevelop 4.1 (Windows7) crash designer

Tags: c#, sharpdevelop, objectlistview

Adding a column using the designer crashes the control with the following message:

```
System.Exception: The control BrightIdeasSoftware.ObjectListView has thrown an unhandled exception in the designer and has been disabled.  
Exception: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader' to type 'BrightIdeaSoftware.OLVColumn'
```

I tried 2 different laptops. On both machines it works fine with VS2010 but crashes the designer in #D

Then I make a fresh install of windows7, .net4, sdk and OLV using VirtualBox in a linux box with the same result.

Can't find useful information in Google so I appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score 1):

You can just go into the designer code and change the column type from System.Windows.forms.Column to new BrightIdeas.OLVColumn  and make sure your columns are also declared as such - after this you can then edit the columns.

Answer (score 0):

It is a [bug](http://bugtracker.sharpdevelop.net/Default.aspx?p=4&i=1879). SharpDevelop is not using the custom column collection editor that the ObjectListView assembly contains. Instead it is defaulting to the column collection editor which is used for the standard System.Windows.Forms.ListView.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem in c#. I use SharpDevelop 4.3.3 and c# 4. I just solved following this step:

- Add object list view (i.e. objectListView1) in the form
- Add olvColumns (i.e. olvColumn1, olvColumn2, etc...) directly in the form... without using column editor.
- In the *InitializeComponent* method of the form (that is called in the constructor of the form), after initialization of olvColumns, add link between object list view and column after the code

```
    [...]
    // 
    // olvColumn4
    // 
    this.olvColumn4.CellPadding = null;

    // after initialization of olvColumns 

    objectListView1.Columns.Add(olvColumn1);
    objectListView1.Columns.Add(olvColumn2);
    objectListView1.Columns.Add(olvColumn3);
    objectListView1.Columns.Add(olvColumn4);

    [...]
```

After this operations, you can reopen form in design mode and check objectlistview columns: you will see there are columns that you created.